# Не удалось открыть сессию для виртуальной машины

Tags: virtualbox

Неожиданно перестали запускаться все виртуалки, и виндовые и линукс с такой ошибкой:

> Не удалось открыть сессию для виртуальной машины <тут имя машины>.
>
> Invalid parameter. (VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER).
>
> Код ошибки: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
>
> Компонент: ConsoleWrap
>
> Интерфейс: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Обновил VirtualBox до последней версии 5.1.16 от 8го марта, но проблема не решилась( запускал также от админа и даже перезагружал комп, но тоже самое(

Comment: Такое у них иногда бывает. Откатитесь до версии 5.0.32 r112930 (более ранние тоже годятся).

Comment: ну нифига себе решение) откатится до самой первой пятерки да с того времени тыщю фиксов проделано. как то мне не хочется этого делать, учитывая то что эмуляторы дроида требует более свежую

Comment: Сочуствую. Я практически уверен, что мои линуксы (в ни разу на обновленной Win-7) будут работать даже в какой-нибудь работоспособной VirtualBox 4-ке от 13-го года (а вот с 5.1.16 та же проблема, что вы описали)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему. До последнего не хотел верить в гипервизор как причину, т.к. во первых он у меня был отключен, во вторых по опыту win8.1 и vb4.x даже при включен визоре виртуалки должны работать но с тормозами. Тут видимо в 10ке мелкософт уже чтото поменяли, так что принудительное отключение hyper-v решило проблему. всем спасибо. очень жаль что вот так вот.